# Does Next.js not need browser history when using Redux?

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to migrate my `React` app to `Next.js`. I keep having below error from `export const history = createBrowserHistory();` in my `configureStore.js`.

> Invariant Violation: Browser history needs a DOM

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from "connected-react-router";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import user from "./modules/user";
import stores from "./modules/stores";
import info from "./modules/info";

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

const middlewares = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)];

const reducer = combineReducers({
  user,
  stores,
  info,
  router: connectRouter(history)
});

export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
  return createStore(
      reducer,
      preloadedState,
      compose(
        applyMiddleware(
          ...middlewares
        )
      )
    );
}
```

I've found that many things need to be changed when migrating React to Next.js as Next is a framework which requires its own code architecture as well as the difference between SSR and CSR. When I studied Next.js tutorials, there is a routing section which says that routing is differentiated based on CSR or SSR. Does that mean I cannot use browser history in Next.js? That's what I'm guessting. I'm still confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. There is different between SSR and CSR. Next.js use **Next Router** for routing for CSR and if you need custom SSR, then you should ask for some help from frameworks like `express`.

By doing the CSR, nextjs will remember browser history and back button works as expected. However if you need to change the route to a very diffrernt route you can use any of these solutions:

```
import Router from 'next/router';
...
Router .push('/about');
```

Or

```
import Link from 'next/link';
...
<Link href="/about"><a>about</a></Link>
```

and if you need to do some extra work before routing then you should use:

```
Router.beforePopState(({ url, as, options }) => {...}
```

Migration would take some time and you need to remember next.js will take over the charge for routing and browser history automatically. Unless you customise it.

Comment: So, should I remove every code about CSR routing such as `ConnectedRouter` and `createBrowserHistory`?

Comment: Yes. You should remove them and think about them in next.ja way

Comment: Thank for clarifying that!